# Is there a widget similar to SwiftUI's Disclosure Group?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a widget similar to SwiftUI's disclosure group?

[image]

Something that shows a view (with animation) and hides it. In my case I'm looking to present/hide text.

So far the closest widget I have found is `Visibility`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is widget called `expansion tile` that is very similar to SwiftUI's Disclosure Group and here you can read about more on official flutter docs  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html, also some tutorial [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/expansion-tile-in-flutter-d2b7ba4a1f4b).

Answer (score -1):

There is also ExpansionPanelList:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html

---

Edit:

```dart
class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> dummyData(int numberOfItems) {
  return List<Item>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<Item> _data = dummyData(8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.expandedValue),
              subtitle:
                  const Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _data.removeWhere((Item currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                });
              }),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```